# How to count nested elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an unknown, complex DOM structure and searching for the max number of nested elements with a given class (`.bar`).

I need a (recursive) method which returns the max levels of nested elements. In this example it should be **3**

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar"> <!-- #1 -->
            <div class="foo"></div>
            <div class="foo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar"> <!-- #1 -->
            <div class="foo"></div>
            <div class="foo"></div>
            <div class="foo">
                <div class="bar"> <!-- #2 -->
                    <div class="foo"></div>
                    <div class="foo"></div>
                    <div class="foo">
                        <div class="bar"> <!-- #3 --> <!-- << this is the "most nested element" -->
                            <div class="foo"></div>
                            <div class="foo"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar"> <!-- #1 -->
            <div class="foo"></div>
            <div class="foo"></div>
            <div class="foo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar"> <!-- #1 -->
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo">
            <div class="bar"> <!-- #2 -->
                <div class="foo"></div>
                <div class="foo"></div>
                <div class="foo"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my approach would be to use `querySelectorAll( '.bar' )`:

```js
let d = 0;

function my_counter(root, depth = 0) {
    //get all items
    let items = root.querySelectorAll('.bar');

    d = Math.max(d, depth);

    //for each item check
    items.forEach((item) => {
        my_counter(item, depth + 1);
    });

    return d;
}
```

This approach looks dirty and resource intensive to me so I look for a better. Also if the count change as elements can get removed `Math.max` doesn't respect that.

Comment: _"This approach looks dirty and resource intensive to me so I look for a better."_ have you benchmarked it? "resource intensive" is relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive function that reduces the queried child elements by a specified selector.

```js
const findMaxDepth = (root, selector, depth = 0) =>
  [...root.querySelectorAll(selector)].reduce((maxDepth, child) =>
    Math.max(maxDepth, findMaxDepth(child, selector, depth + 1)), depth);

const root = document.querySelector('.root');

console.log("Max depth of '.bar':", findMaxDepth(root, '.bar')); // 3
console.log("Max depth of '.foo':", findMaxDepth(root, '.foo')); // 4
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- #1 -->
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- #1 -->
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
          <!-- #2 -->
          <div class="foo"></div>
          <div class="foo"></div>
          <div class="foo">
            <div class="bar">
              <!-- #3 -->
              <!-- << this is the "most nested element" -->
              <div class="foo"></div>
              <div class="foo"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- #1 -->
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <!-- #1 -->
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo">
      <div class="bar">
        <!-- #2 -->
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without iterating elements by simply adding CSS nesting:

```js
function findMaxDepth (className, deep = 0) {
  return document.querySelector(className)
       ? findMaxDepth(className + ' ' + className.split(' ')[0], ++deep)
       : deep;
}

console.log('.bar: ', findMaxDepth('.bar'));
console.log('.foo: ', findMaxDepth('.foo'));
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- #1 -->
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- #1 -->
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
          <!-- #2 -->
          <div class="foo"></div>
          <div class="foo"></div>
          <div class="foo">
            <div class="bar">
              <!-- #3 -->
              <!-- << this is the "most nested element" -->
              <div class="foo"></div>
              <div class="foo"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- #1 -->
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <!-- #1 -->
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo">
      <div class="bar">
        <!-- #2 -->
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly return and update the depth value in your recursive function. Additionally, since you're only interested in the maximum depth of .bar elements, you don't need to use querySelectorAll('.bar') multiple times. Here's a cleaner version of your code:

```js
function findMaxNestedDepth(root, depth = 0) {
  let maxDepth = depth;

  // Get all .bar elements within the current root
  const barElements = root.querySelectorAll('.bar');

  // Iterate through each .bar element and recursively check their nested depth
  barElements.forEach((barElement) => {
    const nestedDepth = findMaxNestedDepth(barElement, depth + 1);
    maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, nestedDepth);
  });

  return maxDepth;
}

const rootElement = document.querySelector('.root');
const maxDepth = findMaxNestedDepth(rootElement);
console.log('Max Nested Depth:', maxDepth);
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- #1 -->
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- #1 -->
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
          <!-- #2 -->
          <div class="foo"></div>
          <div class="foo"></div>
          <div class="foo">
            <div class="bar">
              <!-- #3 -->
              <!-- << this is the "most nested element" -->
              <div class="foo"></div>
              <div class="foo"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <!-- #1 -->
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar">
    <!-- #1 -->
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo">
      <div class="bar">
        <!-- #2 -->
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that determines the maximum depth of elements matching a selector by constructing child selectors:

```js
function findMaxDepth(selector) {
  const find = (lastDepth) =>
    document.querySelector((selector + ' ').repeat(lastDepth + 1))
      ? find(lastDepth + 1)
      : lastDepth

  return find(0)
}
```

It supports arbitrary selectors. If there are no matching elements, it returns 0.

The internal `find` function recursively looks for deeper and deeper elements.
Given an achieved depth, it constructs a selector one layer deeper and checks if there are any matching elements.
If there are, it calls itself with the new depth and returns the result.
If not, it simply returns the passed-in achieved depth.

There is a trailing space in the constructed selector, but it does not affect anything.
You could also use an array to construct it, but it would be less efficient:

```js
Array(depth + 1).fill(selector).join(" ")
```

Here's a Snippet showing it in action:

```js
function findMaxDepth(selector) {
  const find = (lastDepth) =>
    document.querySelector((selector + ' ').repeat(lastDepth + 1))
      ? find(lastDepth + 1)
      : lastDepth

  return find(0)
}

console.log("Max depth of '.foo':", findMaxDepth('.foo'))
console.log("Max depth of '.bar':", findMaxDepth('.bar'))
console.log("Max depth of '.baz':", findMaxDepth('.baz'))

console.log("---")

// You can use abritrary selectors.
// For example, the depth of groups of at least two siblings matching '.foo':
console.log("Max depth of '.foo + .foo':", findMaxDepth('.foo + .foo'))
// Or elements matching '.foo' that are the third child:
console.log("Max depth of '.foo:nth-child(3)':", findMaxDepth('.foo:nth-child(3)'))
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <!-- #1 -->
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <!-- #1 -->
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo">
        <!-- #2 -->
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="foo"></div>
          <div class="foo"></div>
          <div class="foo">
            <!-- #3 - This is the "most nested element" -->
            <div class="bar">
              <div class="foo"></div>
              <div class="foo"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="foo">
    <!-- #1 -->
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
      <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- #1 -->
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo">
      <!-- #2 -->
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="foo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The basic idea (of constructing a child selector) is from @imhvost's answer.